# Styles - Visual Studio code fragment, copy & paste Outlook (HTML) - retain styling?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, email

I'm a fan of the [Son of Obsidian](http://studiostyl.es/schemes/son-of-obsidian) Visual Studio style (white/color letters on dark-gray background).

It's also great that Outlook attempts to retain syntax highlighting, however I use the white default background in Outlook.  The result is that I need to either strip all syntax highlighting on code fragments I email to coworkers, or set the background color of the email darker.

I've tried out the [Copy As HTML](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/98fef791-eb65-4cdf-bf84-077b98c234cf) plugin, however this didn't override the background color for the code fragment in Outlook.

Has anyone figured out a good solution for this kind of workflow?

Comment: Does Outlook have a "paste plain text" option? It might be called "Paste Special..." or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to retain the VS background, but just for the region pasted (or somehow retain the syntax highlighting).  I found this can be done inserting a text box and setting the background.  I guess I need to find/tweak the plugin or Outlook to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is really a late reply :

I use the same theme.
You can refer to this article for the general steps. 
http://codinglifestyle.wordpress.com/2013/05/17/copy-and-paste-formatting-with-visual-studios-dark-theme/

The article though tells how to do the opposite of what we want so instead i came out with this :

```
<style type=”text/css”>pre{background:#344042 !important}</style><pre>
```

and this does pretty much the job.